# Account Balance For Invoice Purposes Access 2010

Tags: expression, ms-access-2010

I have created a new transactions table (tblTransactions) where I can log all my [Debits] (*i.e. invoices*) and [Credits] (*i.e.payments*). From this I can run a query with an an expression to get the Current Account Balance.

However, for invoicing purposes, if I pulled the Current Account Balance as described above, it wouldn't be the 'previous account balance' value I want to display to the customer on the invoice, because it's showing a value which includes the current invoice amount. I want the customer to see the previous balance **PRIOR TO** that invoice.

My current solution uses expressions in a query to calculate this 'previous account balance', but I don't know if could be done another way. Any suggestions on how this could be done better?

I couldn't post a picture of the query b/c I don't have enough reputation points.

Invoice fields I'm trying to populate:

- Invoice Amount
- Previous Account Balance  *(prior to this invoice)*
- Final Invoice Amount

Below are my calculations used in the query

`Invoice Amount: Debit`

`Previous Account Balance: Format([Account Credits]-[Account Debits],"Currency")`

`Final Invoice Amount: Format([Invoice Amount]-[Previous Account Balance],"Currency")`

`Account Debits: Format(DSum("[Debit]","tblTransactions","ClientID =" & [ClientID])-[Debit],"Currency")`
*This formula takes out the value of the current debit in the query

`Account Credits: Format(DSum("[Credit]","tblTransactions","ClientID =" & [ClientID]),"Currency")`

Comment: Each invoice will be one transaction record, which then should relate directly to the primary key on tbltransactions called [TransactionID]. I would potentially have two "unique" items per transaction record; [TransactionID] or [Invoice_Number].

Comment: The ultimate goal, if possible, would be to create just one expression to get the 'Previous Account Balance'.  On a side note, when I run my query with the expressions noted above, I get the correct values. However if I try to sort by any of these fields I get an error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression...".

Comment: An update on my side note. I have found the issue.  I had some field names on tbltransactions which had some spaces.  I removed the spaces and the sort feature is working without error.  Just a rookie mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution "quick and dirty" is to find add a condition to your query excluding the record on which you are working (current invoice).
If you have an ID, you can add a WHERE condition to your DSUM, excluding the current record.
Let's assume IDTransact is ID field of tblTransactions, your WHERE condition should be

"ClientID =" & [ClientID] & "AND IDTransact <> " & CStr([IDTransact])

I assumed the ID is a long (autonumbering).

Hope this can help you.
Let me know.

Bye

Comment: I modified `Account Debits: Format(DSum("[Debit]","tblTransactions","ClientID =" & [ClientID])-[Debit],"Currency")' to `DSum("[Debit]","tblTransactions","ClientID =" & [ClientID]),"Currency" & "AND TransID <>" & CStr([TransID]))` and get the correct value.  As noted above the ultimate goal would be to create just one expression to get the 'Previous Account Balance'. On a side note, when I run my query with the I get the correct values. However if I try to sort by any of these fields I get an error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression...".

Comment: An update on my side note. I have found the issue.  I had some field names on tbltransactions which had some spaces.  I removed the spaces and the sort feature is working without error.  Just a rookie mistake :).